# Batch file can't read ApplicationSettings file

Tags: c#, .net, application-settings

I have a console .Net application that's executed via a batch file passing one parameter. I'm working on migrating this setup to a different server and for some reason I'm getting errors on the new server seeming to indicate that ApplicationSettings file can not be read. The setups on both servers look the same to me, permissions look OK also. Both servers are Win 2008. Any suggestions are appreciated.

Here are the details:

**Batch file:**

```
auto-batch-processes.exe 2
```

**auto-batch-processes.exe.config:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <appSettings file="Config\ApplicationSettings.config" />
  <connectionStrings configSource="Config\ConnectionStrings.config" />
  <startup>
```

.............

**Config\ApplicationSettings.config**

```
<appSettings>
  <add key="log4net.Internal.Debug" value="true"/>
  <add key="Environment" value="LIVE" />
......
  <add key="Email" value="blabla@blabla.com"/>
......
</appSettings >
```

Upon execution of the batch file, I'm getting the following error

```
D:\Apps\Auto-Batch-Processes>auto-batch-processes.exe 3

Unhandled Exception: System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: address
   at System.Net.Mail.MailAddress..ctor(String address, String displayName, Enco
ding displayNameEncoding)
   at auto_batch_processes.Managers.NotificationManager..ctor() in c:\Workspace\
MSI\Auto Batch Processes\auto-batch-processes\Managers\NotificationManager.cs:li
ne 25
   at auto_batch_processes.AbpBase..ctor() in c:\Workspace\MSI\Auto Batch Proces
ses\auto-batch-processes\AbpBase.cs:line 18
   at auto_batch_processes.JobProcessor..ctor() in c:\Workspace\MSI\Auto Batch P
rocesses\auto-batch-processes\JobProcessor.cs:line 12
   at auto_batch_processes.Program.Main(String[] jobs) in c:\Workspace\MSI\Auto
Batch Processes\auto-batch-processes\Program.cs:line 21
```

And here the application code snippets where it presumable blows up:

```
public NotificationManager()
        {
          _fromAddress = new MailAddress(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Email"]);
            _environment = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Environment"];
```

...........

```
public MailAddress(string address, string displayName, Encoding displayNameEncoding) {
            if (address == null){
                throw new ArgumentNullException("address"); 
            }
            if (address == String.Empty){ 
                throw new ArgumentException(SR.GetString(SR.net_emptystringcall,"address"), "address"); 
            }
```

Comment: That isn't a batch file error, it's an error in your `auto-batch-processes.exe`. Is `auto-batch-processes.exe` in the same folder as `auto-batch-processes.exe.config`? Does the `Config` folder exist on the new server?

Comment: Is the same version(s) of .NET Framework installed on the new server?

Comment: exe and exe.config are in the same folder and .Net Framework is the same on both servers. I actually got it to work (sort of) yesterday. Hardcoded the full path for ApplicationSettings.config and it clicked. I then changed it back to relative path and it still worked... I can't explain why, but this confirms that there's probably a permission issue of some kind.